# Generate Random Number with no duplication

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

I want to generate 20 Random numbers in between 1 and 50 with no duplication of numbers and store into an array.

For Example if button click one random number generate like 5 it store in array then if again click on button and one more random number generate if that random number is available in array then generate another and match with array if that random numbers is not there then store in Array.

I want Some Easy code, some code are available in this site but i can't understand those codes. And I am using Java 8 and eclipse Oxygen.

I am using this simple code for generating Random numbers

```
    Random rand=new Random();
    i=1;
    i=1+rand.nextInt(8);
```

Comment: "I want Some Easy code, some code are available in this site but i can't understand those codes." So why not link to the relevant question, and give details about what you don't understand in that code? There's no point in just asking the same question again - you're likely to get the same kind of code, which you still won't understand, having wasted the time of people answering...

Comment: Stackoverflow is for providing solutions to problems, it is not a code writing service.  If you want some easy code, hire someone to write it for you.  I charge €80 per hour.

Comment: but I am not available at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate random numbers with no duplication by generating an array of increasing numbers and then shuffling it.

Answer (score 0):

You may generate a random number, store it into an array and check every new number against this array. This might slow down your process.

As long as an array with 50 integers will not fill all your memory, you can create `int[50]` witch integers from 1 to 50 and remove (or create a new array without) the randomly choosen array element. It will not provide a good performance but it seems that this is not really important.

Answer (score -2):

Try somenthing like this:

```
private List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private Integer generate() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int aux;
    do {
        aux = rand.nextInt(49) + 1; // Random numbers in between 1 and 50
    } while (numbers.contains(aux)); // Prevents duplication
    return aux;
}

public void btnClick() {
    if (numbers.size() < 20) { // Limits to 20 numbers
        numbers.add(generate()); // Store in an list
    }
}
```